# Animated CGAffineTransformTranslate after CGAffineTransformScale results in "jumping" frame

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewanimation, cgaffinetransform

Consider a simple Xcode 6 Swift "Single View" project. AutoLayout is deactivated.

The view (all Autoresizing is deactivated) contains one 100x100 UIImageView (**image**) and two buttons "Move" and "Resize", triggering the respective functions in the ViewController:

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var image: UIImageView!

    @IBAction func resize(sender: UIButton) {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0) {
            self.image.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(self.image.transform, 2, 2)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func move(sender: AnyObject) {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0) {
            self.image.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(self.image.transform, 10, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Button **Move** shall move the image by 10 points to the right. Button **Resize** shall scale the image by 2 in each dimension. Each transformation shall be animated with a duration of 1 second.

Each button for itself works perfectly fine. **Problems however arise** as soon as the buttons are clicked sequentially, e.g. first **Move** (I wait for the animation to complete) and *then* **Resize** (or the other way around). In this case, the second animation does not originate where it is supposed to. Instead, the image first "jumps" several points into the wrong direction and then resumes the intended animation to the (correct) new position.

My intention is to trigger multiple animated transitions individually after each other, so this "jump" effect is a major annoyance. Thanks a lot for any ideas on how to solve the issue. Please let me know in case I can supply further details.

**Edit:** Please let me highlight again that all AutoLayout and Autoresizing is *deactivated* and hence should not cause the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `CGAffineTransformScale`, change the frame to achieve the same effect.

Move the view:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.BeginFromCurrentState, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.theView.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(self.theView.transform, 0, 20)
        }, completion:nil)
```

Scale the view:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0) {
        self.theView.frame = CGRectInset(self.theView.frame, 0.05 * self.theView.frame.width, 0.05 * self.theView.frame.height)
    }
```